# Copy and paste data to rearrange a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, loops, range, vba

Here's a screenshot that demonstrates the problem

[image]

Here's a copy of the spreadsheet.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qihuvbe5c80su4/Data_rearrange_trial.xlsm?dl=0

Each spreadsheet relates to a single university 'unit' and holds data on the performance of a sample of students within a set number of 'traits'. The traits are organised in columns that are adjacent to one another and for data processing purposes I need to copy them so they are all in a single column. I also need to replicate each student's row of 'label' data next to their copied 'trait' data. I also need to copy the trait names or labels as well and paste them in the appropriate position.

1- I've used user input to define the parameters of what needs to be copied (all the spreadsheets have a similar set up). Is there any way to detect the parameters of the copy ranges and paste ranges?

2- At some point in the macro I need to tell it the name of the worksheet I'm working in (Set TargetWorkSheet = Worksheets("Input Data")). Is there a way to eliminate the need for an explicit naming of "Input Data" for example something like (ActiveWorkBook) or something along those lines?

3- This is a sort of follow on from question 2. I'm going to be using the macro in multiple spreadsheets. What's the best way to make it universally available, so I don't have to copy and paste code repeatedly from spreadsheet to spreadsheet.

4- Are there better ways to implement this macro? I made sure to make the code efficient (e.g. I was looping from cell to cell and then changed that to work on ranges instead). Any other good practice that I've missed?

```
Sub Rearrange()

Dim CopyRowNr As Integer                'Variable determining the row coordinate where data is to copied from.
Dim CopyColNr As Integer                'Variable determining the column coordinate where data is to be copied from.
Dim RecordsNr As Integer                'Variable determining the number of students and thus sets the number of row copy operations (nested while loop)
Dim TraitsNr As Integer                 'Variable determining the number of traits to be copied and sets the number of copy repetitions (first while loop)
Dim PasteRowNr As Integer               'Variable determining the row coordinate where the data is to pasted to.
Dim PasteColNr As Integer               'Variable determining the column coordinate where the data is to be pasted to.
Dim CopyRowCounter As Integer           'Counter for the nested while loop that cycles through each data-set (comprised of 3 columns and multiple rows).
Dim CopyColCounter As Integer           'Counter for the first while loop that cycles from one trait data-set to the next
Dim CopyColCounterLim As Integer        'The iteration limit for the first while loop
Dim CopyRowCounterLim As Integer        'The iteration limit for the nested while loop
Dim CourseRowLabelCol As Integer        'Variable to determine row coordinates for copying the row labels
Dim CourseRowLabelRow As Integer
Dim UnitRowLabelCol As Integer
Dim UnitRowLabelRow As Integer




Dim TraitsCopyRange As Range            'Range to copy traits data from
Dim TraitsPasteRange As Range           'Range to paste traits data into
Dim CourseRowLabelsCopyRange As Range   'Range to copy course info from
Dim CourseRowLabelsPasteRange As Range  'Range to paste course info into
Dim UnitRowLabelsCopyRange As Range     'Range to copy unit info from
Dim UnitRowLabelsPasteRange As Range    'Range to copy unit info into

Dim TargetWorkSheet As Worksheet

Set TargetWorkSheet = Worksheets("Input Data")

RecordsNr = InputBox("Enter the number of students recorded")       'User input to define operational parameters x 3
CopyRowNr = InputBox("Enter the number of first row of data")
CopyColNr = InputBox("Enter number of first column of data")
TraitsNr = InputBox("Enter the number of AoL traits recorded") - 1  'User input, but '1' is deducted because the first trait column remains in place and doesn't need copying.


PasteRowNr = CopyRowNr + RecordsNr                                           'Operational parameters calculated from input values x 7
PasteColNr = CopyColNr - 3                                                   ' 3 column offset from the copy column. Consider pros and cons of defining the offset of 3 as a variable.
CopyColCounterLim = TraitsNr
CourseRowLabelCol = CopyColNr - 6                                            ' 6 column offset from the copy column
CourseRowLabelRow = CopyRowNr
UnitRowLabelCol = CopyColNr - 11                                             ' 11 Column offset from the copy column
UnitRowLabelRow = CopyRowNr

Cells(CopyRowNr - 2, CopyColNr - 3).Copy        ' One-time operation to copy the trait number of the first trait column to the row label area
Cells(CopyRowNr, PasteColNr - 4).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


While CopyColCounter < CopyColCounterLim

       Cells(CopyRowNr - 2, CopyColNr).Copy            'Copy PLO Trait labels
       Cells(PasteRowNr, PasteColNr - 4).Select        'Select and paste PLO Trait with a column offset of -4 and on the same row as the paste row for this iteration.
       ActiveSheet.Paste

        With TargetWorkSheet

          Set TraitsCopyRange = Range(Cells(CopyRowNr, CopyColNr), Cells(CopyRowNr + RecordsNr, CopyColNr + 2))             'Defining the ranges to copy the traits from and paste them into as offsets of the main parameters input
          Set TraitsPasteRange = Range(Cells(PasteRowNr, PasteColNr), Cells(PasteRowNr + RecordsNr, PasteColNr + 2))

            TraitsCopyRange.Cut                 'Copy and paste trait data
            TraitsPasteRange.Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

          Set CourseRowLabelsCopyRange = Range(Cells(CopyRowNr, CourseRowLabelCol), Cells(CopyRowNr + RecordsNr - 1, CourseRowLabelCol + 2))  'Defining the ranges to copy the course info row labels from and paste them into as offsets of the main parameters input
          Set CourseRowLabelsPasteRange = Range(Cells(PasteRowNr, CourseRowLabelCol), Cells(PasteRowNr + RecordsNr, CourseRowLabelCol + 2))

            CourseRowLabelsCopyRange.Copy
            CourseRowLabelsPasteRange.Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

          Set UnitRowLabelsCopyRange = Range(Cells(CopyRowNr, UnitRowLabelCol), Cells(CopyRowNr + RecordsNr - 1, UnitRowLabelCol + 1)) 'Defining the ranges to copy the unit info row labels from and paste them into as offsets of the main parameters input
          Set UnitRowLabelsPasteRange = Range(Cells(PasteRowNr, UnitRowLabelCol), Cells(PasteRowNr + RecordsNr, UnitRowLabelCol + 1))

            UnitRowLabelsCopyRange.Copy
            UnitRowLabelsPasteRange.Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        PasteRowNr = PasteRowNr + RecordsNr 'Shifting the PasteRowNumber to the next position in the spreadsheet.

        End With

    CopyColNr = CopyColNr + 3 'Shifting the Copy Column Number to the next position in the spreadsheet


    'CopyRowCounter = 0
    CopyColCounter = CopyColCounter + 1

Wend


End Sub
```

Comment: In terms of making the macro universally available, you could create the macro in a separate spreadsheet which then looks in a specified folder to find the set of spreadsheets that you want to run the code on. The simplest (but not most elegant) solution is to have a cell in the master spreadsheet where you paste the link of the folder path. If you like this idea I can explain it more over message - nice one for getting your first macro running

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful, so it's like a batch operation on a bunch of spreadsheets! I'll try and make it the more elegant way ..

Answer (score 0):

For tasks like this Microsoft introduced GetAndTransform in Excel 2016. To use this functionality in earlier Versions (2010 and 2013) you have to install Power Query as Add-In.

Looks that you basically have to perform a pivot-operation on multiple columns here. Please find an example here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8u0i7mo2kycia4q/SO_Data_rearrange_trial.xlsm?dl=0

The code is pretty basic:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    CreateStudentID = Table.AddColumn(Source, "StudID", each Text.Replace([MMU ID Number], "MMUID", "")),
    ChangeToNumber = Table.TransformColumnTypes(CreateStudentID,{{"StudID", type number}}),
    FillDownPLO = Table.FillDown(ChangeToNumber,{"PLO"}),
    UnpivotCat = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(FillDownPLO, {"Unit Code", "Unit Description", "Department", "Cluster", "PLO", "Course Name", "Course Code", "MMU ID Number", "StudID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    MergePLOWithCat = Table.CombineColumns(UnpivotCat,{"PLO", "Attribute"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    ReorderCols = Table.ReorderColumns(MergePLOWithCat,{"StudID", "Unit Code", "Unit Description", "Department", "Cluster", "Course Name", "Course Code", "MMU ID Number", "Merged", "Value"}),
    Pivot = Table.Pivot(ReorderCols, List.Distinct(ReorderCols[Merged]), "Merged", "Value")
in
    Pivot
```

Actually you could do this all using the UI only.
Also if this is all made for further dataprocessing, you could collect your data from different workbooks all into one Excel-sheet.